# Minecraft scoreboard targeting all entities when filtered

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok, so let me explain. I have 3 scoreboards set up: `use`, which tests for when a player breaks an emerald block, `att` to move the `use` score over to, and `targ` which is set when someone is being targeted, which should be a 10 block radius that is not the executor. The problem is that  `targ` is given to everyone in the 10 block radius, including the executor.

Here are the commands that are fine.
`testfor @a[score_use_min=1]` which is on a clock, running into `scoreboard players set @a[score_use_min=1] att 1` into `scoreboard players set @a use 0` into the command block with the problem, this one:

`execute @a[score_att_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[r=10,score_att==0] targ 1`. What's wrong with it? Why is every entity in the 10 block radius given the `targ` score of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> /execute @a[score_att_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[r=10,score_att= **=** 0] targ 1

You have a second equals sign, breaking syntax. The parameter is ignored for being invalid, thus the parameter set only contains `r=10`.

```
/execute @a[score_att_min=1] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[r=10,score_att=0] targ 1
```

However, keep in mind that players & non-player entities will not have a score of 0 to detect if they are not instantiated into the scoreboard. That is, if the targets have not had a score set yet, you won't be able to target them with `score_att=0` because they have no score whatsoever.

A quick fix is to add 0 when necessary, which preserves the scores of those that are already tracked but forces other targets that aren't tracked to have a default score of 0.

```
/scoreboard players add @a att 0
```